# Need cross gdb for device

Tags: gdb, embedded-linux

I installed **gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf** cross-compiler on Ubuntu 12.04, and now I am able to build a program for embedded device. Where can I find cross gdb for debugging?

gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf reference contains gdb-arm-linux-gnueabihf in the Related Packages list, which seems to be the debugger that I am looking for. But this package is not available.

Comment: Try toolchain from http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/download.html

Comment: @anishsane - Thanks, I have already tried it, but device vendor recommends gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf. Now I need to find (or possibly to build) cross-debugger for this device.

Comment: @anishsane - can you recommend good embedded Linux forum? I don't post such question here, because such questions are immediately closed :(

Comment: I think, you can get in touch with community like beagle-board, etc. (It's a very active google group.) There you will get good help at least for arm+linux combination. It will be specific to beagleboard, but I think, for simple requirements, they can guide you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recommend getting **gdb** from the [Linaro toolchain](https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries) rather than the Ubuntu repositories. Download gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2012.10-20121022_linux.tar.bz2 from [here](https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries/trunk/2012.10) and you'll find:

- `bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb`
- `arm-linux-gnueabihf/debug-root/usr/bin/gdbserver`

The latter is statically linked and of course built for ARM Linux.

Assuming you have networking already set up to your target board, copy `gdbserver` to it and run:

```
$ gdbserver --multi :2345
```

On your development machine, run:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb
(gdb) target extended BOARD-IP-ADDR:2345
(gdb) set remote exec-file /bin/true
(gdb) run
```

and you're up and running with remote cross debugging.

Links to the Linaro bug tracker, mailing list and web forum are [here](https://www.linaro.org/developers/). They're very active in ARM Linux toolchain, kernel, QEMU development as you can see from their release notes.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. Nice to see that there are embedded developers in this forum.

Comment: For me arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb doesn't start on a 64-bit machine do you know if it is only for 32bit?

Comment: @eactor, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/297151/how-to-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-system-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: ok somehow the output of the programm is issued to the target board instead of forwarded to the devlopment machine, is that normal and can i change it?

Comment: @eactor, ask that as a new question tagged with "embedded-linux" and provide details of how you're connecting to the target board and starting your program. The short answer is _yes_ ;)

Comment: @scott I did thx in advance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995734/gdb-server-output

Comment: Thanks! Needed this to realize I can do exactly the same with `gdbserver` and `arm-linux-androideabi-gdb` on Android devices.

Comment: I'm trying to push this and run this on arm android device, but it is not liking the file, looks like this is file, getting, not executable: magic 7F45

Comment: @domen - Were you able to get the gdbserver from linaro to work on arm 64 bit processor ? I can see a similiar link - https://blueprints.launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries/+spec/aarch64-build but there are no downloadable items

Comment: @badri if you're talking about Android, there's now a `gdbserver64/gdbserver` on target and a unified (all arch) `gdb` (prebuilt in NDK package) for host.

Comment: Thanks domen. It is actually for arm processor.

Answer (score 8):

You need to install the gdb-multiarch package, then run gdb-multiarch command to remotely debug your target.

Comment: That solved it for me, thanks! I'd much rather install a package from the official repositories, than from a third-party website.